# MVC3 routing issue(hide atributes name)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

Hy!
I have this controller:

```
      public ViewResult Hotel(string hotelSupplierCode, bool displayAllRooms, bool resend)
    {
        HotelModel model;
        if (resend)
        {
            model = (HotelModel)Session["HotelDetails"];
            HotelManager.ResendHotel(model.Hotel.Id);
            model.Hotel.Status = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            model = HotelModel.GetGotel(hotelSupplierCode, displayAllRooms);
        }
        Session["HotelDetails"] = model;
        return View("Hotel", model);
    }
```

and this route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Hotel", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{hotelSupplierCode}/{displayAllRooms}/{resend}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Hotel", action = "Hotel", hotelSupplierCode = UrlParameter.Optional, displayAllRooms = UrlParameter.Optional, resend = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The problem is that when I access the view the returned URL is soemthing like that:

```
http://localhost:49575/Hotel/Hotel?hotelSupplierCode=3711&displayAllRooms=False&resend=False
```

but I want something like that:

```
http://localhost:49575/Hotel/Hotel/3711/False/False
```

So how I can hide the atribute names? If i put the second URL manualy it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is due to the order of your routes.  Routes must be placed in order from the most specific to the most general, usually ending with the default route defined in a new project.

Make certain that you place the Hotel route before the default route.

Comment: Great!  When and where do I collect?  Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

Try route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Hotel",
            "Hotel/Hotel/{hotelSupplierCode}/{displayAllRooms}/{resend}",
            new { controller = "Hotel", action = "Hotel" }, 
            new { hotelSupplierCode = @"\w+",displayAllRooms = @"\w+", resend= @"\w+"}
        );
```